# Set property from custom action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm new to wix, and trying to do the following:
I'm converting our current MSI from installing to program files (per machine) to installing in local app data (per user).
But, since this MSI can also be deployed to an entire organization, and since this deployment can run in the system session, I need to figure out the console session's local app data path during the installation process, since I don't want our app to be installed in the local app data dir of the system session.

I know the usual solution is to schedule the MSI to install on the next logon of the 'standard' user, but the demands I received instruct me to install the MSI and run the application afterwards at the same moment, without logging on/off, restarting etc.

So, what I want to do, is to run an immediate custom action which will run another exe I'll create, this exe will return the path of the console session's local app data dir, and use this return value in the installer, by storing this value in a property.

From what I read this far:

1. I can't get a return value from a custom action.
2. What I need to do is to compile a c# dll (I program mainly in c#), in which I'll define a custom action which will contain the logic of getting the console session's local app data dir, and once I have this path, store it inside a property defined in the WXS file.

Did I understand correctly?
Is there a different way to accomplish what I need?
Any tips/tricks/articles/examples to go over?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to achieve per-user / per-machine install. You can just use `WixUI_Advanced` template, i.e. `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />`. It provides this functionality out of the box. Have a look at the official documentation:

https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look, I wonder how will it handle an installation from a system session when it is configured to be installed per machine with 'WixUISupportPerUser '
Thanks! I'll report back